# Handle GPU memory with Celery

Tags: python, tensorflow, memory, parallel-processing, celery

I'm working on an API to search for objects in videos. There will be several users and I'm in the process of managing process concurrency.

I have 2 differents tasks :

- Task A taking **2Go of GPU memory**
- Task B taking **8Go of GPU memory**

For the example, let's say i have **8Go GPU memory**.

So, task A can be parallelize to 4 differents tasks, task B need all GPU.
Is it possible to say to celery that task B has a "weight" of 4 tasks.

**Example :**

Tom launch 4 Task A, then 2 Task B, and 2 task A.

1. Celery handle A1, A2, A3 and A4 (B1, B2, A5, A6 waiting)
2. Celery handle B1 (B2, A5, A6 waiting)
3. Celery handle B2 (A5, A6 waiting)
4. Celery handle A5 and A6